# @Get decorator not working correctly in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, decorator

I am using @Decorators in my Restful Node application.

```
@Get('/:id')
getUser(@Response() res: any, @Params('id') id: string) {
    this.getOneById(res, id)
}

// In Base Controller
async getOneById(@Response() res: any, id: number) {
    const item = await this.getOne({ id })

    if (item) {
        res.send({
            success: true,
            data: item
        })
    } else {
        this.errorHandler(res, 'No Data with provided id')
    }
}
```

I have defined `getOneById` function in base controller and path it's `id` from Params decorator.
But `id` is wrong when I tried to log by `console.log(id);`
Anyone can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `async` in decorate function

Comment: Working fine to me.